# MS Access VBA Reverse Geocode

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, geolocation, geocoding

I am using Access 2010 and am trying to reverse a geocode.  I want to specifify a lat\long location then the result to be shown in a listbox.  I have a form, with a list box and a command button.  The command button has the following onclick event: (I have X out my lat\long address : -) )

```
Dim XMLDoc As New DOMDocument
Dim XMLNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Long
Dim lat As Double, lng As Double


XMLDoc.Load "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=XX.XX,-X.XX&sensor=false"


Do Until XMLDoc.ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

If Len(XMLDoc.Text) = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("No data!")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set XMLNode = XMLDoc.selectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address")

For i = 0 To XMLNode.childNodes.length - 1

Me.List1 = XMLNode.childNodes(i).baseName & ": " & XMLNode.childNodes(i).Text

Next i
```

However, I am not able to retrieve any results - the list box is blank - where am I going wrong?

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `addItem` method as described here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835328(v=office.15).aspx

so applying to your code it should be (but I have not tested)

`Me.List1.AddItem Item:= XMLNode.childNodes(i).baseName & ": " & XMLNode.childNodes(i).Text`

Comment: Thanks for this.  This has worked but now it is just populating the list box with the word 'False'....

Comment: Looks like I've answered your question then. Your problem now is why your xmlnode code is not working. I'd ask a new question for that part. Please accept this answer.